# Get resource manager access token from msal login

Tags: azure, adal, azure-ad-msal

I am creating a web app (javascript/HTML) that enables me to manage azure resources on a user's behalf. I want to use MSAL to login a user and obtain an access token for the Azure Resource Manager. Is this possible? When I try the below code the popup is restricted to work/school logins (I want it to be accessible to all accounts) and fails when I use a work email stating the app is not supported for your organization _____ because it is in an unmanaged state.

Here is what I do:

I create a MSAL object.

```
    var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, acquireTokenRedirectCallBack,
        {storeAuthStateInCookie: true, cacheLocation: "localStorage"});
```

I then call loginPopup and pass in management.azure.com as the scope.

```
myMSALObj.loginPopup("https://management.azure.com/.default")
.then(
function (idToken){
myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent("https://management.azure.com/.default")
})
```

Note: I also tried setting the scope to: https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation.

I have registered an Azure app and the manifest specifies requiredResourceAccess to include Azure Service Management and "signInAudience" is set to "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount".

How do I use MSAL login with a scope that requests access to azure resources?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use MSAL to login a user and obtain an access token for the
>   Azure Resource Manager. Is this possible?

Yes, it is possible.

> How do I use MSAL login with a scope that requests access to azure
>   resources?

The scope `https://management.azure.com/.default` is correct. Make sure the authority is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common`. I think you might missed something when you register the application. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa#register-your-application) to check again.

**Update**

Here are the detailed steps for your reference.

1.Click App registrations(Preview)->New registration
[image]

2.Click Authentication->check Access tokens and ID tokens.
[image]

3.Update your code with this client id.

```
var applicationConfig = {
    clientID: '2ac327fd-4803-4ed3-****31fc8dfbbf18', //This is your client ID
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common", 
    Scopes: ["https://management.azure.com/.default"]
};
var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, acquireTokenRedirectCallBack,
    { storeAuthStateInCookie: true, cacheLocation: "localStorage" });

function signIn() {
    myMSALObj.loginPopup(applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(function (idToken) {
        //Login Success
        showWelcomeMessage();
        acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph();
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Now you will be able to login with the work and school accounts from Azure AD and personal account.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I re-did the app registration and am running into the same problems: 1. User can only use a company or school account, 2. When I test the login with my company account I get the previously mentioned warning about the app not being supported for your org. If the scope is set to https://management.azure.com/.default, will users only be allowed to login with a company or school account and will only admin's be able to grant access to my app?

Comment: @user2871322 I have updated my answer. You can check the detailed steps. By the way, did you use the company account which is from Azure AD?

Comment: @user2871322 Do you have any other concerns regarding this?